# Open Source alternative for Angular 2x Geolocation autocomplete

Tags: angular, geolocation, openstreetmap

I am looking for a service that lets me use geolocation autocomplete functions like [ng4-geoautocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-geoautocomplete) , which looks awesome and works perfectly, but works with google maps API.

Is there something similar, where you dont have to register for an Google API Key, like a library based on Open Street Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a loot at Nominatim OSM

"Nominatim is a search engine for OpenStreetMap data...", for more details, check this link https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/

Also check this article out [leaflet-and-nominatim](https://derickrethans.nl/leaflet-and-nominatim.html), here you can find a good example of using Nominatim with Leaflet. This example based on jQuery, but the main concept for Angular framework will be the same.

Hope this will help you :)